# PCSF_46008 Cannot connect to domain to look up service coreservices/UserManagementService

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am getting the following error while connecting to Informatica repository: [PCSF_46008] Cannot connect to domain to look up service [coreservices/UserManagementService].

I restart Informatica (10.2.0) in the services, and ORACLE DB is also operational, but I am still unable to access to the repository.

If I reinstall the informatica server & client tools, will I lose all my existing workflow/mapping objects?
Any clarification you can provide would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer the question first -

> If I reinstall the informatica server & client tools, will I lose all my existing workflow/mapping objects? Any clarification you can provide would be highly appreciated.

--> No, the repository is stored in oracle DB. Unless you drop oracle DB, repository and domain database will stay. But if you reinstall, informatica configurations like $INFA_HOME, config files .odbc.ini etc. will change ( which is obvious).

Now going back to your real problem - I think informatica need some port numbers to white listed/opened. Also whereever oracle is installed, is it accessable using sql client from informatica server? You can check this - Login using informatica user, open a sql terminal( like sqlplus), and then try to connect to the Oracle DB using informatica metadata user and password.

Comment: I reinstalled everything though the same error still persists also while installing I can access to Informatica server but post installation, I can't access to Informatica server page either. Please help or can we meet up in zooms/teams? I will share the screen.

Comment: can you pls open command prompt or shell and try to connect to the Oracle DB using sqlplus ? Did you install pre-requisite softwres?

Comment: Yes I can connect to Oracle DB using sqlplus with system user or any other user . I have installed Oracle DB,sql developer,informatica server and client tools. Now the issue is I can't access to informatica server admin console page and from client tools also I can't connect to repository even though while installing oracle db connection success,repository and Integration service created and services available. Not really sure what went wrong..

Comment: is it a local system ? or your laptop? are all ports open like 6001 to 6070? where is admin console pointing? Are al informatica services up and running fine? Are they running as local user or admin ?

Comment: I have installed it on my personal laptop. Domain=Domain, Gateway Host=localhost, Gateway Port=6005. I am not sure how I can view if all the services are running up as I can't access to that admin console page anymore..though in services option on laptop, I can start those services but it will stop after few secs automatically.

Comment: go to run and type `services.msc` - you should be able to see the services that are ruining on your pc. search for informatica. sometime it runs under local user and doesnt have access to all the files etc. lets ensure it first. You can check some screenshot here https://www.tutorialkart.com/informatica-tutorial/what-is-informatica/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: No,it doesn't run untill I start it..and it will stop automatically after few secs.

Comment: which means some issue with the service. Are you running it with admin user ? If you are not sure, Run Command prompt with `run as Admin` and then follow below startup instructions https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/installation-for-powercenter-and-data-quality/appendix-a--starting-and-stopping-informatica-services/starting-or-stopping-informatica-from-a-command-prompt.html

Comment: Yes I am running as administrator and even I followed all the above-mentioned steps, the same issue still persists, it will connect for few secs and disconnect automatically. (I checked in exception logs which states  [[DOM_10022] The master gateway node for the domain is not available. Electing another master gateway. Wait for the election of the master gateway node to  complete. If the problem persists, verify that the master gateway node is running.] How do I fix it?

Comment: OR is there anything I need to make changes in the Windows Defender firewall?